# Selenium + node running multiple test at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Situation:

- I've setup 4 computers with different versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer and connected them to a selenium grid (hub).
- I can use selenium-webdriver in node and target a test to different browser/machine combinations.
- Selenium grid performs without any problem.

However when I call my Getscreen() function multiple times everything is good until one of the test servers has a problem (like timeout).

The error is captured with 
`Client.controlFlow().on('uncaughtException', function(e) {...`
in the function.

But strangely this listener does not get destroyed with the function completing it's run. So if I've already called the function 50 times and test 51 fails I get 51 error messages.

My node code is like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var HubIP = '192.168.1.201';

var Resolutions = [{
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
}, //0
{
    width: 1680,
    height: 1050
}, //1
{
    width: 1600,
    height: 900
}, //2
...
];

function writeScreenshot(data, name) {
  name = name || 'ss.png';
  var screenshotPath = '../tests/';
  fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
};


function Getcreen(urltoget,resolutionN,WaitN,browsernameN,TableRowID)
{
    var xCapabilities = {};

    if (browsernameN=="ie8") { xCapabilities = { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '8', platform: 'WINDOWS' }; }
    if (browsernameN=="ie9") { xCapabilities = { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9', platform: 'WINDOWS' }; }
    if (browsernameN=="ie10") { xCapabilities = { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '10', platform: 'WINDOWS' }; }
    if (browsernameN=="ie11") { xCapabilities = { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11', platform: 'WINDOWS' }; }
    if (browsernameN=="chrome") { xCapabilities = { browserName: 'chrome',  platform: 'WINDOWS' }; }
    if (browsernameN=="firefox") { xCapabilities = { browserName: 'firefox', platform: 'WINDOWS' }; }

    var Client = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('http://'+HubIP+':4444/wd/hub').withCapabilities(xCapabilities).build();

    Client.controlFlow().on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
        console.error('**** ERROR ***** \n ' + e);
    });

    Client.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(parseInt(WaitN,10));
    Client.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000);
    Client.manage().window().setSize(Resolutions[parseInt(resolutionN,10)].width,Resolutions[parseInt(resolutionN,10)].height);

    Client.get(urltoget).then(function() {
        Client.getTitle().then(function(title) { console.log(browsernameN+": " + title); });
        Client.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
        writeScreenshot(data, TableRowID + '-'+browsernameN+'.png');
    });
    Client.quit();
}
```